# FFTW and OpenCV's C++ interface, real and imaginary part in Mat output

Tags: c++, opencv, fftw

I'm trying to code a FFT/IFFT function with FFTW 3.3 and OpenCV 2.1 using the C++ interface. I've seen a lot of examples using the old OpenCV formats and I did a direct conversion, but something doesn't work.

The objective of my function is to return a Mat object with the real part and the imaginary part of the FFT, like dft default OpenCV function does. Here is the code of the function. Program gets blocked with memory problem in the lines that copy im_data to data_in.

Does somebody know what am I doing wrong? Thank you

```
Mat fft_sr(Mat& I)
{

double          *im_data;
double          *realP_data;
double          *imP_data;

fftw_complex    *data_in;
fftw_complex    *fft;      

fftw_plan       plan_f;

int width     = I.cols;
int height    = I.rows;
int step      = I.step;

int             i, j, k;

Mat realP=Mat::zeros(height,width,CV_64F); // Real Part FFT
Mat imP=Mat::zeros(height,width,CV_64F); // Imaginary Part FFT


im_data = ( double* ) I.data;
realP_data = ( double* ) realP.data;
imP_data = ( double* ) imP.data;


data_in = ( fftw_complex* )fftw_malloc( sizeof( fftw_complex ) * width * height );
fft     = ( fftw_complex* )fftw_malloc( sizeof( fftw_complex ) * width * height );

// Problem Here
for( i = 0, k = 0 ; i < height ; i++ ) {
    for( j = 0 ; j < width ; j++ ) {
        data_in[k][0] = ( double )im_data[i * step + j];
        data_in[k][1] = ( double )0.0;
        k++;
    }
}


plan_f = fftw_plan_dft_2d( height, width, data_in, fft,  FFTW_FORWARD,  FFTW_ESTIMATE );


fftw_execute( plan_f );

// Copy real and imaginary data
for( i = 0, k = 0 ; i < height ; i++ ) {
    for( j = 0 ; j < width ; j++ ) {
        realP_data[i * step + j] = ( double )fft[k][0];
        imP_data[i * step + j] = ( double )fft[k][1];
        k++;

    }
}



Mat fft_I(I.size(),CV_64FC2);
Mat fftplanes[] = {Mat_<double>(realP), Mat_<double>(imP)};
merge(fftplanes, 2, fft_I);

fftw_destroy_plan(plan_f);
fftw_free(data_in);
fftw_free(fft);
return fft_I;   
}
```

Comment: What is `step` set to? What exactly means "Problem Here"? What happens when you add the line `std:cout << i << "/" << j << std::endl;` to the body of the inner loop of the nested loop struct producing the problem?

Comment: step is fixed to 4096 (8 bytes (CV_64F, 64 bit float) * 512 (row size)), they are 512x512 images. Adding this line, it throws a 'access violation reading location 0x04331000 at i=64, j=506

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `step` wrong. It is meant to index into `Mat::data`. Since you already casted `Mat::data` to `double*` when assigning it to `im_data`, you can index into `im_data` "normally":

```
data_in[k][0] = im_data[i * width + j];
```

When using `step` the correct way to index is:

```
data_in[k][0] = ( double )I.data[i * step + j];
```

---

**Update:**

Try to access your images row-wise. That way you avoid running into problems with stride/step, while still exploiting fast access:

```
for (int i = 0; i < I.rows; i++)
{
    double* row = I.ptr<double>(i);

    for (int j = 0; j < I.cols; j++)
    {
        // Do something with the current pixel.
        double someValue = row[j];
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, after testing it several times, it doesn't work. Yesterday, I changed the lines that you suggested (in the two ways) and I didn't get memory errors and I supposed that the result was OK. After testing in different scenarios, it doesn't work properly (getting the same error in the same line or in similar memory access lines in fft/ifft function). When no memory errors, the function doesn't return the FFT of the image properly.

Comment: @aristos I guess you are still doing some indexing wrong elsewhere. Is there a reason why you are accessing `Mat::data` directly? Why not use `Mat::at()` first for safer memory access and improve performance later? Anyway, before I can give anymore help, you have to update the code in your question and describe where exactly what error is happening.

Comment: `Mat::at()` is slower than accessing `Mat::data` directly, isn't it? Well, I tried that and it's so much time cost, that's why I'm looking for alternatives

Comment: @aristos I updated my answer with a new suggestion. Please re-work your question to a minimal, yet complete example in case this doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but when you are using fftw you need to initialize  `fftw_complex    *data_in`
only after creating the plan for the fft, if i recall correctly when you create the plan it sets all the 
`*data_in` values to 0.
so allocate before the plan and initialize after!

Answer (score 0):

Statement

```
im_data = ( double* ) I.data;
```

defines `im_data` as `double` pointer to image data.
I think that should be mandatory that `I` was a double values image.